# Can I query the neo4j database with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I have created a geohash neo4j database for NYC Taxi data.
Now the next step is to visualize it within a map, for that i choosed Leaflet as a Javascript library.
with static data i can plot geohash data in Leaflet:

[image: geohash-leaflet]

but now i want to query that data from the neo4j database  and render it.

so is it possible to do that or only with a server side scripting language(node.js,php...)  ?

## Update

i found a simlair question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213258/how-to-access-neo4j-dataset-through-javascript) , the solution is to query the database with ajax however it dosen't work for me and i get "error" in the console:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
            statements: [{
                statement: 'MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)'
            }]
        });
   $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7474",
        type: "POST",
        data: body,
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
        .done(function(result){
            console.log(result);

        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

first the url for the database is : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit" and not "http://localhost:7474".

then after changing that i got an unauthorized error in console , that means i need to add my user/password to my ajax call, this is done by a function called beforeSend like this:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("neo4j"+ ":" + "your_neo4j_password"));
            }}
```

so the final Ajax Solution is :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("neo4j"+ ":" + "password"));
            }}
            )
            .done(function(result){
                 console.log(result);
            }) 
            .fail(function(error){
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to query Neo4j from client-side Javascript with [Neo4j Driver for JavaScript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver).

I have used this in a couple of projects.

You can either download the driver and include in your HTML file like:

```
 <script src="lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
```

Or just use the CDN link like:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/neo4j-driver@X.Y.Z/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rajendra Kadam's answer is correct.

First you need to install `neo4j-driver` by:

```
npm install neo4j-driver
```

in a directory probably one level higher than the `web/` directory of your `node.js` server.

Then you need to put the `neo4j-web.min.js` into the `web/` directory, where your client-side JavaScript can load.

Then you add the line in your HTML:

```
 <script src="js/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
```

The file `neo4j-web.min.js` is located in `node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/browser/`.

Then in your client-side JavaScript, put:

```
var driver = neo4j.driver(
    'neo4j://localhost',
    neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password') );
```

Then you have successfully opened the driver. (You may need to set your password correctly or you'll get an authentication error.)

Note that you **DON'T** need this line on your client-side JavaScript:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');
```

because it is for **server-side** `node.js`.